# Unable to load multiple content blocks in Django 4.0 using TailwindCSS

Tags: django

```
Folder Structure:
mysite
-theme
--templates
---main_base.html
---theme_footer.html
---theme_menu.html
-home
--templates
---home
----main.html
```

main.html:

```
{% extends "main_base.html" %}

{% block content %}
blah blah
{% end content %}
```

main_base.html:

```
{% load static tailwind_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% tailwind_css %}
    </head>
    <body class="bg-blue-100">
        <nav>
            {% block navbarn %} 
            {% endblock %}
        </nav>
        
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        
        <footer>
            {% block footer %} 
            {% endblock %}
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

theme_menu.html:

```
{% extends "main_base.html" %}
{% block navbarn %}
home
{% endblock %}
```

theme_footer.html

```
{% extends "main_base.html" %}
{% block footer %}
<h1>this is a footer</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

So I was able to setup Django with Tailwind following the instructions on the plugin page. But I can't get the base theme to show multiple blocks. It doesn't show the menu nor the footer, just the base html template with content from main.html. Can't get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is running into this issue, you can't use multiple extends. You instead, include it in your base.

For me, I removed the {% extends %} tags from the ancillary pages, and then included them in my theme_base.html like:{% include 'theme_footer.html' %}